# Monitor pending security updates on various Linux servers with Zabbix

Tags: linux, bash, zabbix

Hello beautiful people,

I'm trying to monitor pending security updates with Zabbix on various linux servers.
Found a script that should work across platforms, but I'm hitting some snags.

Debian-based servers (Ubuntu) are giving me errors from "Bad substitution" to "functions error" when running it. Suspecting bash, dash not being compatible.

RedHat-based servers (CentOS, Alma), can't seem to make it work with only checking for security updates, like "yum updateinfo list security".

Suse, didn't even try to fix it, only got a few of these :/

Original post on Medium that I followed
https://medium.com/caendra-tech/monitoring-system-updates-with-zabbix-7a888510a457

Is there a kind and capable person here that would correct and possibly split the script by distro so that it would work?

Thanks to all of you here, learned a bunch from you, but obviously still not enough ;)

Script in question

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# From https://github.com/kvz/bash3boilerplate
# Require at least bash 3.x
if [[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -lt "3" ]]; then echo "bash version < 3"; exit 1; fi

# Exit on error. Append || true if you expect an error.
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# Bash will remember and return the highest exit code in a chain of pipes.
set -o pipefail

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

timestamp_file="/run/zabbix/caendra_check_update"
update_interval="86400" # 1 day
timestamp_file_mtime="0"
os=""
epoch=$(date "+%s")
tmpfile=$( mktemp --tmpdir=/run/zabbix )    
outfile="/run/zabbix/zabbix.count.updates"

function _detectOS {
    if [[ -e /etc/centos-release ]]; then
        export os="centos"
    fi
    if [[ -e /etc/debian_version ]]; then
        export os="debian"
    fi
}

function _check_last_update {
    if [[ ! -e $timestamp_file ]]; then 
        export update_needed=y
        touch $timestamp_file
    else
        timestamp_file_mtime=$(stat -c %Y $timestamp_file )
    fi

    if [[ "$((epoch-timestamp_file_mtime))" -gt "$update_interval" ]]; then 
        export update_needed=y
    else
        export update_needed=n
    fi
}


function _check_OS_upgrades {
    if [[ "$os" == "debian" ]]; then 
        if [[ "$update_needed" == "y" ]]; then
            apt update &>/dev/null
            touch $timestamp_file
        fi

        pkg_to_update=$((apt-get upgrade --simulate 2>&1 | wc -l) || true)
    fi
if [[ "$os" == "centos" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -e /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/repomd.xml ]]; then
            # if the repomd.xml file does not exists,
            # we assume that this is a new machine 
            # or "yum clean all" was run
            export update_needed="y"
        fi
        if [[ "$update_needed" == "y" ]]; then
            # forced true as the --assumeno option 
            # always returns exit code 1
            yum upgrade --assumeno &> /dev/null || true
            touch $timestamp_file
        fi
        yum_output=$(yum check-update --cacheonly && rc=$? || rc=$?; echo "rc=$rc" > $tmpfile)
        source $tmpfile
        rm $tmpfile
        if [[ "$rc" == "0" ]]; then
            pkg_to_update="0"
        fi
         if [[ "$rc" == "100" ]]; then
            pkg_to_update=$(echo "$yum_output" | egrep -v '^(Load| \*|$)' | wc -l)
        fi
    fi
}
_detectOS
_check_last_update
pkg_to_update=""
_check_OS_upgrades
echo "$pkg_to_update" > $outfile
```

Comment: Becarfull, for Debian in example if you use only "apt-get upgrade --simulate" you got also the package which has a new version without vulnerabilities. Best practices in Debian like is to use unattended upgrades : https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: @Inazo thank you for clarification, but we do not do unattended updates. Updates are done manually after checking that they don't have unwanted consequences, but will still look into that.

Comment: Zabbix is not a vulnerability assessment tool. you should probably look for another tool, better suited for the job. Also, both rpm and apt often hangs, or require internet access to work, or need more time than the Zabbix timeout.

Comment: @Iron Bishop, I am well aware of that it is not a assessment tool, that is not what it's intended use is and not what I expect it to do. We assess updates mostly case by case.
Servers are connected to the internet, otherwise no need for updates. 
The nice thing of the script is that it deposits only the number of updates in a file, Zabbix only reads the number and reports it, so no timeout. Also, timeout can be adjusted, did it with some other scripts, no problem.
If apt or rpm would hang, we would get a warning, so that is also not the problem.
Thank you for your suggestions and warnings